# Ignore all folders in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have many folders that are additional domains, in other words,  multiple domains in a primary domain.

The main domain is in the folder `/public_html` but redirects to a folder `/foo`

Is it possible don't access when write the main domain with some folder that are additional domain?

**Examples:**

With the following folder:

`/public_html    (main domain)
  |__ .htaccess
  |__ /foo       (redirects)
  |__ /bar       (additional domain)
  |__ /foobar    (additional domain)
  |__ /asd       (additional domain)
  |__ ...`

- `http://www.foo.com` redirects to the `/foo`
- `http://www.foo.com/bar` should not access the folder `/bar`, the correct is `/foo/bar`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be 2 scenarios here.

**Scenario 1:** If there is no .htaccess in `/bar/` then you can add this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!foo/).*)$ /foo/$1 [L,NC]
```

**Scenario 2:** If there is a .htaccess in `/bar/` then you can add this rule in `/bar/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?foo\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /foo/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.foo.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/bar/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /bar/$1
```